# Find pom in subdirectories and execute mvn clean

Tags: bash, maven

What is the command for finding all subdirectories which contain pom.xml file and then execute:

```
mvn clean
```

operation in that subdirectory?

I have workspaces that contain multiple maven projects and I want to clean all of them.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Something like this should probably work:

find . -name "pom.xml" -exec mvn clean -f '{}' ;

Comment: adding `-type f` would make this perfect

Comment: Why? In case there's a directory named 'pom.xml' ?

Comment: adding `-depth 2` guarantees only the parent pom of direct subfolders are found

Answer (score 4):

I am using this script, it calls `mvn clean` only on those projects that have to be cleaned (they have a `target` directory):

```
find . -name "target" -type d \
| sed s/target/pom.xml/ \
| tee /dev/stderr \
| xargs -I {} mvn -q clean -f {}
```

The `tee` part is optional, it just prints out the project that is being cleaned.

Answer (score 3):

in general, you would want to issue `mvn clean` on the parent pom, which would clean all children defined as modules, too.

If you don't have and don't want such a parent you'll need to use brute force for this, meaning something like

```
for dir in yourdirectory;
do
  cd $dir
  if [ -f pom.xml ];
  then
    mvn clean
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "pom.xml"  -exec mvn clean -f '{}' \;
```

put this in a file like
'cleanRepo.sh'

execute in unix-terminal or on windows within git-bash:

```
sh cleanRepo.sh
```

for me this works best since i only work with multi-module-projects.